# Javascript Won't Update on Website - Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, updating

About a month ago, I installed a javascript "random quote button" on my sandbox-website. [After great help on the button from the community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825838/javascript-random-quote-works-but-why-wont-the-button-show-up-in-this-div/62825934?noredirect=1#comment111101036_62825934), I was able to move the Random Quote Button wherever I wanted.  Works great.

Now, unfortunately, I haven't invested enough time into learning Javascript since then and have been pushing the rest of the site forward.  I went to tweak the quotes that it can serve up but they won't update.  My local file will only show an old version of the options the button could give.  **Updates to my .js file won't show up on the website.**  In a program like JS Fiddle, the Javascript is as it should be.  Just within my website, it's showing options that aren't even existent anymore...

I've tried things like

- F5
- Control+Shift+J = Console Panel and right-click refresh to Empty Cache and Hard Reload
- clearing the specific cookie which doesn't exist (because local file or because I'm looking for Cache?)

I'm using Visual Studio.  The Random Quote Generator had been working, but upon checking for the first time in 10+ days, it's shuffling old quotes.  In jsFiddle, the Javascript is working correctly.  Is this something in my cache, network, code or what exactly?  Why won't the Javascript update?  Thank you so much.

HTML:

```
          <div class="container-QUOTE">
            <div class="quote-text">
              <h1 id="quote"> You could eat a horse.</h1>
              <p id="author"> - whoever said</p>
            </div>
            <button id="btnQUOTE">Click Here</button>
          </div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#btnQUOTE {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #b82d23;
  color: #17e6db;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Javascript:

```
let quotes = [
    {
        "quote": "1st Quote.", 
        "author": "1st dude"
    },

    {
        "quote": "2nd Quote",
        "author": "2nd dude"
    },

    {
        "quote": "3nd Quote",
        "author": "3nd dude"
    },

    {
        "quote": "4nd Quote",
        "author": "4nd dude"
    },

    {
        "quote": "5nd Quote",
        "author": "5nd dude"
    },
]

    //variables

    const btnQUOTE = document.getElementById("btnQUOTE");
    const quote = document.getElementById("quote");
    const author = document.getElementById("author");


    //event listener

    btnQUOTE.addEventListener('click', getQuote);

    function getQuote () {

        let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

        quote.innerHTML = '<span>"</span>' + quotes[number].quote + '<span>"</span>';
        author.innerHTML = '<span>--</span>' + quotes[number].author;
    }
```

JF Fiddle:  it works here but within Visual Studio/local file the Javascript won't update.  https://jsfiddle.net/wikex004/zo2vxkmr/2/

I want to shift this Javascript to classes from id (#btnQUOTE).  Is doing that for Javascript similar to HTML?  What all needs to be switched within the JS?

---

Within the F12  "network" tab, when I select my js item it shows the code which IS NOT updated.  I suppose I could edit it in there, but why is my old Javascript the only thing that shows up?  (image attached)[image: Entries should just say Quote 1, Quote 2]

Comment: try "Ctrl + F5"?

Comment: I've tried this.  It does not work.  Thank you though

Comment: to behin with press F12 in chrome, go to "network" tab, tick "Disable cache", refresh and check if that helps

Comment: Hi, this does not work.  Thank you, I hadn't this kind of refresh.  It doesn't work, but are people thinking that my local device is just "remembering" an older version of the Javascript?  I'dthink this is a fairly common problem?

Comment: I think it's the cache issue, if your website is currently on your local PC, you can try to rename the script.js and try. If its on your server, you need to check if the server has any cache setup or not. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: Thank you.  I just tried the solution discussed here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675494/chrome-doesnt-recognize-my-changes-on-my-javascript-file-and-loads-old-code  adding "script.js?newversion"  I don't understand why such an added string "will be ignored" but I suppose I'll change the js file name.  This creates a duplicate file with the new name for other HTML files in Visual Studio.  I hope this doesn't cause any other problems with my Javscript.  Thanks for the help